# How to move collection?

Tags: collections

[image]
As you can see in the screenshot, I added the tree, the rock and the ground in the collection, Tree001. And then I was going to move all of them at once. Clicked the tree and G to move. But only the tree was moved.
I selected Tree001 on the right side of the menu, but once you click the tree, Tree is automatically selected.

Comment: You need to select all objects that you want to move. If you want to move all objects that are in a collection you can right-click the collection (Tree001) in the outliner to open the context menu. There select the menu entry "Select Objects". Now now you have them selected and you can move them around. -- Tip: If you right-click the menu entry you can assign a shortcut key. Then you just have to click the collection in the outliner and press the assigned key to select all objects of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!